# Why is there too much on my sys.path?

Tags: python, path, setuptools

I am trying to uninstall some package I'm developing (residing in ...plugin-iqf\test\performance\src), but from within Python shell, I'm still able to import it.

My `PYTHONPATH` is empty, yet ...

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path: print p
...

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-3.3-py2.7.egg
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\catchy-0.1.3-py2.7.egg
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\argparse-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
c:\workspaces\remoteadmin-protocol\implementations\python\src
c:\workspaces\reslasher\src
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygtk-2.24.0-py2.7-win32.egg
c:\workspaces\blizzard\closed-source\plugin-titech\plugin-iqf\test\performance\src
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
c:\Python27\DLLs
c:\Python27\lib
c:\Python27\lib\plat-win
c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
c:\Python27
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages
c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

Where do things like

```
c:\workspaces\remoteadmin-protocol\implementations\python\src
c:\workspaces\reslasher\src
```

come from?

Comment: Why do you feel there is too much? You installed several packages as eggs, and these are added to your path.

Comment: Because I tried to uninstall these packages.  I removed the eggs, but the path remains...

Comment: they are added by `.pth` files, look for them in `site-packages`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: thanks!  Probably, that's the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python looks for `.pth` files in four specific directories, formed by combining `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` on the one hand, and the empty string and (on Windows) `lib/site-packages`. Those `.pth` files can list additional paths to add to `sys.path`, one per line. See the [`site` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site).

You probably have one or more of those; look for such files in `c:\Python27\lib\site-packages`,  but any files with names matching existing eggs you did not uninstall, that start with `import` should be left alone; these generally are hooks to set up namespaced packages.

You could also have a `sitecustomize` module that manipulates `sys.path`. You can see if you have one by trying to import it:

```
import sitecustomize
sitecustomize
```

will either fail with an `ImportError` or echo the path.